# MySQL root login email notification

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux, scripting, mysql-5.7

Is there a script that I can run to get an email when someone else other than me logs in as root?

I'm new to MySQL. These are my contents of `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
*Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.

*innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

*Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging

*changes to the binary log between backups.

*log_bin

*Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.

*The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.

*Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.

*join_buffer_size = 128M

*sort_buffer_size = 2M

*read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

datadir=/var/lib/mysql

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

*Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

port=1433
```

Please suggest a way to get an email alert if someone logs in as root into MySQL.

Comment: Check out the authentication plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go with this but using logs is the simplest way as there is no need of creating table inside mysql to log the root or user login with timestamp as mentioned in : http://www.fromdual.com/sites/default/files/logon_trigger_wp.pdf

I installed logtail and logcheck using yum, then wrote the following script and then created a cron job which runs this script:

#!/bin/sh

if [ -f foundadmin.txt ]
then
    rm foundadmin.txt
fi
if [ -f send.txt ]
then
    rm send.txt
fi

/usr/sbin/logtail2 -f /var/log/mysqld.log -o mysqld.log.offset | grep "root@localhost on  using Socket" > foundadmin.txt

if [ -s foundadmin.txt ]
then
    echo "Subject: MYSQLDB Admin Login on $(hostname)" > send.txt
    cat foundadmin.txt >> send.txt
    /bin/mailx -s "Subject: MySQLDB Admin Login on $(hostname)" myemail@com  < send.txt
    rm foundadmin.txt
    rm send.txt
fi
exit 0

#

this is the cron job to make it run every minute:

#### This is run a cron job in a time interval and mail the admins to notify

- - - - - cd /opt/mysql-check ; ./mysql-notify-script.sh